# Representing numbers by quasilexicographic ordered strings, formula for size of conversion between different alphabets

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, order-theory, formal-languages, number-systems

Let $X_r = \{ 0, 1, \ldots, r-1 \}$ and $X_b = \{ 0, 1, \ldots, b-1 \}$ be two finite alphabets with order's given by their numerical value. Consider the [quasilexicographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order#Quasi-lexicographic_order) (or [shortlex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortlex_order)) order on $X_r^*$ and $X_b^*$. Then we have standard bijection's $\operatorname{r-string} : \mathbb N \to X_r^*$
and $\operatorname{b-string} : \mathbb N \to X_b^*$ given by for example with $r = 2$ and $X_r = \{ 0, 1 \}$:
$$
 \begin{array}{r|l}
   n & \operatorname{2-string}(n) \\ \hline
   0 & \varepsilon \\
   1 & 0 \\
   2 & 1 \\
   3 & 00 \\
   4 & 01 \\
   5 & 10 \\
   6 & 11 \\
   7 & 000 \\
   8 & 001
 \end{array}
$$
and so on. Now consider the following translation function 
$\operatorname{trans}_{~b, r} : X_r^* \to X_b^*$
between these representations of natural numbers given by
$$
 \operatorname{trans}_{~b, r} := \operatorname{b-string} \circ ~\operatorname{r-string}^{-1}.
$$
How to prove that
$$
 |\operatorname{trans}_{~b,r}(u)| = \lceil |u| \cdot \log_b r \rceil
$$
for all $u \in X_r^*$ where $|u|$ denotes the length of a string $u$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s false as written. Take $b=10$, $r=2$, and $u=111$: $\operatorname{2-string}^{-1}(u)=14$, $\operatorname{10-string}(14)=13$, and $|\operatorname{trans}_{10,2}(111)|=2$, but $\lceil|u|\cdot\log_{10}2\rceil=\lceil3\log_{10}2\rceil=\lceil\log_{10}8\rceil=1$.

Comment: You mean $\operatorname{10-string}(14) = 13$, as $\operatorname{10-string}(1) = 0, \operatorname{10-string}(2) = 1, \ldots, \operatorname{10-string}(14) = 13$? Do we have $|\operatorname{trans_{b,r}}(u) - \lceil |u| \cdot \log_b r \rceil | < c$ for some constant $c$?

Comment: @Stefan: Yes, I inadvertently read my table backwards; fixed now. Thanks. I’ll have to think about the new question. In fact, you might want to ask it as a separate question, in order to get more eyes on it.

Comment: Okay, I opened a new thread. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @Stefan: You’re welcome!